# How do I change options file (my.ini) location for Windows?

Tags: mysql-workbench

The location of the options file is greyed out in

> Database/Manage Connections/Local instance MySQL80/System Profile/Configuration file

My options file is located elsewhere.  How do I change this?

[image: Screenshot of Problem]

Comment: Can you share sshot of that.This field should not be greyed out if you select Windows in combobox ...

Comment: Done!  Image added to my original post.  This is a custom installation as I didn't have an option file available, so a manual install did not work.  The large msi put directories where I didn't want them.  Trying to move them with insufficient knowledge caused it to fail.  I went with a custom install using mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.21.0.msi, and located the directories where I wanted them.  The configuration file location was not updated during the install, giving me just one more headache.  Rather than ask and wait I poked around and came up with this work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 'server_instances.xml' must be edited to reflect the location of the options file.  We can locate this file ourselves, as it's usually in our roaming user profile.  Edit the line starting with '<value type="string"key="sys.config.path"' to reflect the options file location.  Alternately we can:

1. Open MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE from the 'Start' menu
2. Connect to the database
3. Select Tools/Configuration/Backup Connections
4. Choose a file name and save the file.
5. Open the archive (I used 7-Zip)
6. Open the file 'server_instances.xml' within the archive (I used
   Notepad++)
7. Look for the line starting with '<value type="string"
   key="sys.config.path"'
8. Edit the value to reflect the full path and file name of your
   configuration file
9. Save your edit back to the archive
10. Select Database\Manage Connections
11. Select the database ('Local instance MySQL80' in my case) and
    delete the connection (Button under the list of connections)
12. Select Tools/Configuration/Restore Connections
13. Open the modified archive (using mySQL Workbench 8.0)

You should see the updated location in Database/Manage Connections/Local instance MySQL80/System Profile/Configuration File.

Answer (score 0):

Can be that upgrading to MySQL Server 8.0 from several versions resulted in old values remaining unchanged in the

```
%AppData%\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml
```

on my machine is `c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\server_instances.xml`
Please open that file and try to search `sys.config.path.lock` and change value from 1 to 0 or remove that xml entry. restart workbench and you should be able to edit that path.

Comment: Possibly, but I removed all files and folders between installation attempts.  I also searched the registry, and removed all references to mySQL and its components.  The only way to be certain would have been to restore my system from backups.  Knowing the file name (server_instances.xml) would allow folks to search for the file and edit it rather than using the export/modify/import method I used.